# How to find an Instance of a class inside a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, class, mvvm, dictionary

If I have been researching this correctly, I got some help before and a user said that it would be good to use a `Dictionary` to store my `Country` and `Places`.

So I create my `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string, NewCountryClass> NTCD = new Dictionary<string, NewcountryClass>();
```

When the user clicks the button it will trigger this class where I wanted it to create a instance of `newCountryClass` inside the `Dictionary` at runtime. It would add the string which would be the `newCountryTitle.Country` and then the `Class`.

```
public void AddCountryCollection()
{

    newCountryClass = new NewCountryClass(newCountry,"");
    Collections.Add(newCountryClass);
    NTCD.Add(newCountryClass.Country, newCountryClass);
}
```

So lets say the user has has added the `Country` which has created this `Dictionary` at **Runtime**, and they have added 4 `Countries`, but now want to go back and add a `Place` label inside the second Country.

This is the `newCountryClass`:

```
private string _country;

public string Country
{
   get { return _country; }
   set
   {
      if (_country.Equals(value))
         return;

      _country= value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => Country);
   }
}

private ICollection<string> _places;
public ICollection<string> Places
{
   get
   {
      if (_places== null)
         _places= new ObservableCollection<string>();
      return _places;
   }
   set
   {
      if (value == _places)
         return;

      _places= value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => Places);
   }
}
```

If they have created 4, and they want to add a `Place` to the list inside that `Country` of the **second** one they created, how would I find it?

Comment: You'd use the key that you saved it with - in this case, the country. The point of a dictionary is that it's a key/value map. You stored it with the Country, so you need to look it up with the country. There's no inherent notion of "the second value that was added" - wouldn't the user actually just pass in the country? The context is a bit confusing here...

Comment: @Ben - you really need to read up on .NET data structures and concepts. I know Jon Skeet mentioned this on a previous question, and it's excellent advice.

Comment: @JonSkeet The user will pass in a `Country`, so they might pass in `England`, `Spain` and `France`. These will be listed, then when they `Right-Click` and 'Add Place' on one of the `Countries`, they can then add a `Place` (Which is in the `newCountryClass` as a `ICollection`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the key you stored:

```
NTCD["GER"].Places.Add("New Place inside GER");
```

If you only want to know the second one, either take a `List<NewCountryClass>` and iterate by index with `for`or take a `OrderedDictionary`. It takes object key, object value as parameters on add and you can access it via `NTCD[3]`.

[OrderedDictionary Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, worked fine, I just passed a String Variable of what title they selected.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `Dictionary`, so there's no concept on an item being at a particular index. Instead, an item is at a particular key, which in your case is the value of your `Country` property.

If you want to get an item by a numeric index they you need to use a data structure like a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).